# /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 11

Tags: ios, macos, xcode8, codesign, macos-sierra

After upgrading to macOS 10.12 Sierra and Xcode 8, code signing is broken for me.

Every time I try to sign an app, no matter how simple, I get `/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 11`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the reason was that I had to **delete expired certificates from Keychain**.

Hope I saved you a few minutes of aimless, frustrated troubleshooting.

Comment: This also worked for me (after running clean). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue today, but in my case, there were no expired certificates in Keychain. Trick from https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/65055 worked for me:

> I got both issues with a fresh new certificate, so it was not just about the certificate being old.
>   But I got around it by specifying the certificate by ID instead of name — first getting the ID via:
>
> `security find-identity -p codesigning`
>
> and, from the output of that, copying the long hex ID for the key I want, and pasting that into my codesign invocation:
>
> `sudo codesign -s 001CA54450805B2D8D1646793D0339BA7EB931D1 --timestamp=none /opt/local/bin/ggdb`

Answer (score 1):

Retry running `codesign`.

Occasionally, we encounter build failures in our CI system from `codesign` with exit code 11 for no apparent reason. Looking in `Console.app` I see a segmentation fault in thread `Dispatch queue: com.apple.security.XPCTimeStampingService`. I understand that this means that some error occurred trying to talk to the timestamp server.

This isn't the same issue as OP, but I found this question while investigating my issue.